# Installed php53 but still displaying php 5.1.6 in phpinfo()

Tags: php, centos, nginx, php53

I am running `nginx 1.0` on `centos 5.6`. I had `php 5.1.6` installed and running and then decided to uninstall it and switch to `php 5.3`. I ran the following commands:

```
[user@server]$ /etc/init.d/nginx stop

[user@server]$ yum remove php php-*

[user@server]$ sudo yum install php53-cli php53-common php53-devel php53-gd php53-mbstring php53-mysql php53-soap php53-xml php53-xmlrpc php53-bcmath php53-snmp

[user@server]$ /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Now, when I view the output of `phpinfo()` in a browser, it still reads 'PHP Version 5.1.6'.

What step(s) did I miss?

Comment: PHP does not run within Nginx, simply use your PHP init script to restart PHP and you should be good.

Comment: @Martin F - Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP does not run within Nginx, simply use your PHP init script to restart PHP and you should be good.

Other guy kinda hinted at the right thing, is it possible to split an acceptance?

Comment: I just had to run `/etc/init.d/php-cgi restart` and it was fine!

Answer (score 2):

Are there some old php processes still running?  Stop nginx, check for any php processes running (depends on how you're running php stuff under nginx), kill any and restart if it's a persistent PHP FPM and then try again?